# Artifactory 7.x - pypi proxy errror

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

I have a local Pypi repository with simple-default layout. It has anonymous read access granted. I am using this repository to store my libraries.
After the upgrade from Artifactory 6.x to 7.x it is not possible to install any library using pip; it worked in 6.x. Following errors are returned on `pip install my-python-lib`:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='host', port=8081): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=30.0)")': /artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host', port=8081): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/ (Caused by 
ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='host', port=8081): Read timed out. (read timeout=30.0)"))
```

Setting longer `--default-timeout` doesn't work as well.

When I try to open host/artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/ in the browser, it returns following error (after about 2 minutes):

> 502 Proxy Error
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an
> upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET
> /artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/.
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: I found a workaround for this issue. `--default-timeout` option is deprecated and currently `--timeout` should be used. This way I get the installation going. The issue is probably related to misconfigured tomcat on the artifactory machine. Will keep digging and share the results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a reverse proxy(Nginx or HTTPD) is configured on top of Artifactory and Artifactory 7.x has a different configuration when compared to Artifactory 6.x. I would recommend referring to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-reverse-proxy-configuration-for-artifactory-7-x-and-above/) for more insights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking the same, so I configured my pip.conf to bypass the reverse proxy server using direct address to artifactory instance.  Didn't help as well.

Comment: what happens when you run Art_IP:8082/artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/ over the browser? And as you have bypassed the reverse proxy are the errors same or a different error is shown?

Comment: With browser I can open the Art_IP:8082/artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/ instantly. However, if I go to Art_IP:8082/artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/ I get 502 error. Sometimes it returns all the deployed version, but in most cases I get 502 proxy error.

Comment: tail the artifactory-service.log and artifactory-request.log and run the Art_IP:8082/artifactory/api/pypi/my-python-repo/simple/my-python-lib/ and check if anything is printed there, usually an error or warning should be there. Please share it here